# One-taped RAM vs Multi-taped RAM

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines

In Turing Machine, we know that there's (fine-grained complexity) difference between one-tape, 2-taped and multi-taped TM, even though they could be simulated efficiently.

(Well, actually I'm not quite sure they are indeed seperated: i.e. $TIME(t)\neq TIME_{2-taped}(t)\neq TIME_{multi-taped}(t)$ )

But today I'd like to focus on RAM model, is there any complexity seperation between one-taped RAM model and multi-taped model? Though we might expect it be quite small because of random accessibility.

Comment: The RAM model doesn’t have any tapes.

Comment: It seems RAM model is to use a $log(n)$-bit index to access certain cell on a tape.

Comment: Having more than one “tape” gives you no advantage at all. That’s a nice exercise for you.

Comment: I'm not sure about that.
A "tape-manner" turing machine would require zigzagging to simulate its multi-taped version. In RAM model, it seems we still need zigzagging except that we only need log time to jump to that specific location.

Answer (score 3):

Random-access machines support the following operation in constant time:
$$
x \gets M[y],
$$
where $M$ is the memory array, and $y$ is an index whose allowable size depends on the exact model. Whether $M$ is an array of bits or an array of words depends on your exact model.

If you had several different memory arrays, say $M_1[y],\ldots,M_r[y]$, then you could simulate the command
$$
x \gets M_i[y]
$$
with the command
$$
x \gets M[ry + i]
$$
which also takes constant time.

Therefore there is nothing to be gained by allowing several "memories".

Comment: The integer arithmetic you performed before memory access, i.e.
$ry+i$, isn't that at least log time?

Comment: It depends on the model. In the unit cost RAM it will take unit time. You could also transform your program so that for each variable $y$, it also computes $ry+i$ for $i=1,\ldots,r$. The resulting overhead will be $O(r) = O(1)$.